# "Give it in for your dad."

Tags: phrase-usage

In the movie *Juliet, Naked*, Ethan Hawke's character says in a scene:

> These are my sons, Cooper and Jessie. Come here, guys. Give it in for your dad. ([clip on YouTube](https://youtu.be/2oCN-KOhPjI?t=55))

He gestures for a hug. "Give it in for someone" sounds very strange to my ear though. People say "bring it in" when asking for a hug. Has anybody else heard "give it in for" or "give it for" used as a hug suggestion?

Comment: Just listened to this 10 times and can't make sense of it. Never heard the phrase you mentioned. Closest I know of is *give it up for* (= *applaud; cheer*), which is not really appropriate here.